# Почему возникает ошибка: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Tags: javascript, функции

Почему при таком коде:

```
    const someFunc = () => {}
    console.log(typeof someFunc) // "function" 
    // Все прекрасно работает
```

А в таком случае получаю ошибку:

```
    console.log(typeof () => {}) 
    // Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list
```

Что это за ошибка, почему она возникает, и почему, если подставить переменную или cтандартную функцию, то все работает так, как ожидалось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсер не может понять, что разделяют пробелы в этом выражении. Он думает, что все, что слева от `=>`, - это параметры стрелочной функции. Поставьте скобки вокруг определения функции:

```js
console.log(typeof (() => {}));
```